# Extract time from datetime object and compare with string time

Tags: python

In python, I have a datetime object in python with that format.

```
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

In other classes, I'm using this object. When i reach this object,i want to extract time from it and compare string time.
Like below;

```
 if "01:15:13" == time_from_datetime_object
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not converting your string also to a datetime object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the strftime method:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_time_str = '2021-01-15 01:15:13'

datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
if "01:15:13" == datetime_object.strftime('%H:%M:%S'):
    print("match")
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. Thanks for answering. If you like the question feel free to upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare it as string:

```
 if "01:15:13" == datetime_object.strftime('%H:%M:%S'):
```

Answer (score 1):

Use its [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime.datetime.time#datetime.datetime.time) method to return a `time` object, which you can compare to another `time` object.

```
from datetime import time

if datetime_object.time() == time(1, 15, 13):
    ...
```

You may have to be careful with microseconds though, so at some point you might want to do `datetime_object = datetime_object.replace(microsecond=0)`, should your `datetime` objects contain non-zero microseconds.